# Mimic the browser zoom in CSS and JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to mimic the browser zoom (control+/-)feature. The problem is that I also want to increase the div size proportionally, so the usual method of font size adjustments are out; I want to zoom the entire page, including divs and images. Ok, I got that bit working using

```
$('body').css('MozTransform','scale(' + currFFZoom + ')');
```

This is what I currently have,  http://jsfiddle.net/rLw0quL3/

The issue is that while I can zoom, the divs don't wrap within the page the same as they do when I use the inbuilt browser zoom. I'm using the transform and zoom function in css, but there might be an better method?

Comment: `currIEZoom is not defined` your link doesnt work.. correct it

Comment: Maybe you want something like that : 


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294744/jquery-plugin-to-simulate-browser-page-zoom-text-zoom

Comment: you should set the transform-origin:0 0 ;, defaut is from center, that's why you loose part of it on the left :)  http://jsfiddle.net/rLw0quL3/2/

Comment: @GCyrillus, that does make it look much better.

Comment: @Charly, I think that is the right idea, setting jQuery('body').css('zoom', jQuery(window).width() / contentWidth);. Unfortunately, I've not been able to get it to work in my jsfiddle or I would post a working example.